# Multiple row selection

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and having issues selecting multiple rows.

I have followed the explanation on this [link](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html) . A few of the rows are selectable, while other rows don't get selected. There is no error in the console.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var selected = [];

        $('#myTable').dataTable({


            "aaSorting": [ ], // Prevent initial sorting
            "sAjaxSource": "getList",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "sServerMethod" : "POST",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                    aoData.push( { "name": "param", "value": "paramValue"} );
             },
             "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
                if ( $.inArray(data.packetId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                    $(row).addClass('selected');
                }
              },
             "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "packetId"},
                    { "mData": "packetName" }
             ]
        });

        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var id = this.id;
            var index = $.inArray(id, selected);

            if ( index === -1 ) {
                selected.push( id );
            } 
            else {
                selected.splice( index, 1 );
            }

            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        } );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Apparently you're not returning `DT_RowId` field. From the [description](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html).

> Demo uses a unique ID assigned to the TR element (this is done automatically through the use of the `DT_RowId` special property returned as part of the object given by the server for each row) to track which rows are selected and reselect them is appropriate on a draw.

> **SOLUTION**

Replace this line:

```
var id = this.id;
```

with the code below:

```
var data = $('#myTable').DataTable().row(this).data();
var id = data.packetId;
```

> **NOTES**

Please note that there is [Select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension that is much easier to use, see the code below:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    select: {
        style: 'multi'
    }
} );
```

However you would need to include additional JS file for the extension.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/multi.html) for demonstration.

Comment: Well, thanks!
I followed your advice and did that exactly.But this is not helping. Still I am able to select only a few rows and not all and the funny part is that I have noticed that I am able to select only alternate rows.

Comment: I haven't tried the Select extension, a but from the extension it is not very clear about how will it return the Packet ID.

Comment: @vkm, I agree, there is a page on [Selected items retrieval](http://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration#Selected-items-retrieval) but most likely it will work for client-side processing mode only. If you're interested, I wrote article [Row selection using checkboxes](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) that uses similar technique with some enhancements.